# How to copy OberservableCollection List in listview from api query items to new listview

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I'm having trouble copying data from one ObservableCollection to another.  I have an api call GetItemsAsync from http that puts the response into a model called ShipList.cs.  Inside of ShipList.cs there is ShipCatalog[] ships.  I have created a second model called HangarList.cs with HangarCatalog[] hangars.  I have a page that displays the master list of ships (ShipsList) I want the user to select the ship (ShipList.name is bound to this particular ListVIew.  I tried to use .Where() to filter ShipList to only the match to the selected item and copy that data to HangarCatalog. I'm getting Cannot convert GallogForms.Api.ShipCatalog to GallogForms.Api.HangarCatalog using the following code.
ViewModel

```
      private ShipCatalog _selectedShip;
       public ShipCatalog SelectedShip
        {
        get {return _selectedShip; }
    set
    {if (_selectedShip != value)
    _selectedShip = value;
    id = _selectedShip.id;
    CopyShipData();


    private async void CopyShipData()
            {
                var _container = Items.Where(s => 
        s.name.FirstOrDefault().ToString() == id.ToString()).ToList();
            foreach (var item in _container.Where(s => 
    s.name.FirstOrDefault().ToString() == id.ToString()).ToList())

              //  var items = await _gallogClient.GetItemsAsync<ShipList>();
             //   foreach (var item in items.ships.Where(s => 
      //  s.name.FirstOrDefault().ToString() == id.ToString()).ToList())
                {
                    Hangars.Clear();
                    Hangars.Add(item);
                }
            }
```

I haven't found any answer yet, and I've read plenty, that can address my situation.  myShipsList is bound to a new model I've created in the API that perfectly mirrors ShipCatalog[].

I've also keep running across answers that suggest ListViewItem.Item or in my case SuggestedShipView.Items.  .Items is not an option for my ListViews in the view model.

AddShipPage.xaml

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <SearchBar x:Name="HangarListView" Text="Add To Your Fleet!"
                       TextChanged="HangarList_TextChanged" 
                       BackgroundColor="Azure"
                       />
            <Grid>
                <ListView x:Name="SuggestedShipView" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding selectedShip}"
                          BackgroundColor="Silver">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>

                  .....................
```

ShipList.cs (API Query)

```
    [ApiPath("ships")]
        public class ShipList : ApiQueryable
        {
            public ShipCatalog[] ships { get; set; }
        }
        public class ShipCatalog : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 
            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string uri { get; set; }
            public int rsi_id { get; set; }
            public string img { get; set; }
            public string mfr { get; set; }
            public string flyable { get; set; }
            public string scu { get; set; }
            public string value { get; set; }
            public string bgcolor { get; set; }
            public string color { get; set; }
            public string role { get; set; }
            public bool _isVisible { get; set; }
            public bool IsVisible
            {
                get { return _isVisible; }
                set
                {
                    if (_isVisible != value)
                    {
                        _isVisible = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

}
```

HangarList mirrors ShipList perfectly with the exception it's named HangarList, public HangarCatalog[] hangars

And Finally, the query which populates ShipCatalog[]
AddShipViewModel

```
      Items.Clear();
            var items = await _gallogClient.GetItemsAsync<ShipList>();
            foreach (var item in items.ships.ToList())
            {
                Items.Add(item);


      }
```

No error messages per se, but I have not been able to structure a method to complete this task.  If you would like to see the entire project to see more of what I have going on, http://github.com/dreamsforgotten/GallogMobile

Comment: when the user selects an item from the first list, what data do you want displayed in the second list?

Comment: Name, manufacturer, value, scu,  value, flyable, and image in a grid layout I haven't designed yet.   Edit : I might need to tap this list for its values in other parts of the app in the future if why I created the hangarlist model.

Comment: First, that sort of UI really doesn't work in a ListView.  Second, it sounds like you want the datasource for the 2nd control to just be the item selected in the first.  You shouldn't need to do any complex transformations or copying of the data.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do,  and the second list view may or may not remain a list view.  Currently i was planning on replicating shippage. Xaml the same data displayed.  I'm not so much concerned about the list view itself so much as populating hangar catalog with the selected items from SuggestedShipList.

Comment: "populating hangar catalog with the selected items from SuggestedShipList" - this implies that you can selected multiple items from the first list?

Comment: No one at a time.  It implies that after adding a ship from the master ship list to your personal ship list that you can go back and add another.  Actually the plural on selected items was to imply that I need not only shipcatalog.name that is what you are clicking on, but I need the other values as well, img, scu, flyable, etc

Comment: Pretty much I want people to say, oh here's the master list of every available ship, well I need to click this one, and this one etc.  In the end, HangarList.HangarCatalog should be the exact same as shiplist as far as values, but only have the selected ships they chose from the master list.

Comment: It's even better if you make it clear in pictures and list the relationships between them.

Comment: I wanted to be as detailed as possible incase I were overlooking something.  The gist of it is I have 2 observablecollections and I want to share data from 1 into another (never the other way around), and do that via SelectedItem in Listview.

Comment: Could you please post more details about the datasource with data structure and reference relationships?

Comment: Sure I'm doing an api call and it's returning 3 types of data strings int and bool.  This is external api outside the main Forms project.  Using MVVM as well.  So I do my api call and populate a model named ShipsList.cs which contains ShipsCatalog[] ships.  I'm calling this Catalog into my new page as an observablecollection.   I also have a model that mirrors shipscatalog called HangarsCatalog hangars.  I want to select items from ShipsCatalog and append that to HangarCatalog.  ShipsCatalog is every available ship and it's data, and Hangars catalog is the users personal list of ships and data

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clear on my goal.

Comment: In general, we  use method :`s1.Equals( s2 );`  to compare strings.

Answer (score 0):

when you tap or select an item in a `ListView`, the second parameter of the event handler will contain a reference to the item selected/tapped.  You just need to cast it to the correct type.  Then you can reference all of its properties as needed

```
private void SuggestedShipView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
  // e.Item is the specific item selected
  ShipCatalog ship = (ShipCatalog)e.Item;

  // you can then use this ship object as the data source for your Hangar list/control,
  // and/or add it to another List that is just the items the user has selected

}
```

Comment: I appreciate your time and energy.  I'm a complete idiot because I just cannot figure it out.  So I went with what you supplied and added this to the code behind.

private void SuggestedShipView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
ShipCtalog ship = (ShipCatalog)e.Item;
hangar.flyable = ship.flyable;
hangar.scu = shpi.scu
etc etc
}

My "myShipsList" listview is still empty

Comment: as I already mentioned, using a ListView to display the properties of a single item really isn't going to work.  I also don't understand why you're copying property-by-property - are hangar and ship of different types?  If so, why?

Comment: ListView SuggestedShipsView only list name that's so the list isn't cluttered  myShipsList will only display name as well it's on top of SuggestedShipsView.  That way you can see you've added a Caterpiller ship or a SuperHornet, etc.  But, this is all on a page that displays called AddShipPage.  When you exit that page then you are back on Hangar page.  I figured since HangarCatalog is an observableitem I can grab HangarCatalog and populate it with all the ship details of each ship ListViews on AddShip are short list, and Hangar Page displaying HangerCatalog is the full list of values per ship

Comment: You can use the bindings to specify which properties of a complex object to display.  You do not need to create special classes that only have some properties and not others.

Comment: I understand that.  I'm trying to create a whole new binding around HangarCatalog to match ShipCatalog only holding the ships that a user selects.  I will bind that entire Catalog to HangarPage and display the items inside of HangarCatalog as necessary.  So HangarCatalog needs every item ShipCatalog has just not the same amount of ships that populate those items.

Comment: To your "I don't understand why you're copying property-by-propery" Because I have found no way to do this.  That's the only way I was able to structure my code without error and it's not even good enough since my myShipsList still remains empty.